# BroadcastReceiver multiple instances

Tags: service, broadcastreceiver, multiple-instances

The set up I have is:

An Activity that creates and registers a BroadcastReceiver every time it starts. In addition it starts a Service which listens for new sensor data and sends Intents to the BroadcastReceiver. My problem is that each I close the Activity, I stop the Service and unregister the BroadcastReceiver and if I start the Activity again, I get two instances of the BroadcastReceiver with the old data that is not changing and new data constantly refreshing.

I would like to know if there is a way to have only one instance of the receiver? (maybe make it static or add a flag similar to launchMode="singleInstance"). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I solved this problem. The reason for having multiple receiver data, was not multiple instances of the receiver itself but a separate thread that was instantiated multiple times and was never finished.